# Expected value of squared distance between two points in unit disk

Tags: probability

Let $X$,$Y$ be two points chosen uniformly at random in the unit desk, and let $D$ be the distance between them. Prove the expected value of $D^2$ is equal to one.

The problem is taken from the book Weighing the Odds by Williams, which I've been self studying. Just before the problem is stated, he hintfully reminds the reader he doesn't intend to give problems that require just the ability to solve integrals. Unfortunately the best approach I can come up (sketched below) with uses essentially just integrals and relies on knowledge of density functions of compositions of random variables, which aren't topics the author has covered yet at that point in the text. Any better solutions?

(Using the pythagorean theorem, D^2 is the sum of the difference in the x and y-coordinates of the two points, so enough to calculate that the expected value of the sum of the difference of the x-coords is 1/2. The density function for the x-coordinate is $f(x)=\sqrt(1-x^2)$ (appropriately normalized), so one should calculate the integral $\int_{-1}^1 (x-y)^2 f(x)f(y)dxdy$)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2299709/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are points in the unit disc then $\lVert v-w \rVert^2 = \lVert v \rVert^2 + \lVert w \rVert^2 - 2 \langle v, w\rangle$.  The expectation of the last (inner product) term is zero by symmetry considerations.  The expectations of $\lVert v \rVert^2$ and $\lVert w \rVert^2$ are equal and readily computed.