# Expected Euclidean Distance

Tags: circles, expected-value, uniform-distribution

Let $ S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2+y^2 < 1\}$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$. Let $(X_1, Y_1), (X_2, Y_2),$ be independent, both having uniform distribution over $S$. Let $D$ denote the Euclidean distance between $(X_1, Y_1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2)$. Show that $E(D^2) = 1$.

Here I integrated
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-Y_2^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-X_1^2}} (X_1 - X_2)^2 + (Y_1 - Y_2)^2 dX_1 dY_1 dX_2 dY_2$$

Comment: Please type up your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that it can be searched by others.

Comment: I edited your question to fix the latex. Would you like me to write it as an integral too? Just let me know which variables correspond to which bounds and I'll fix it

Comment: Also: I'm not sure what your question is... Are you asking us to verify your solution?

Comment: HallaSurvivor well the four limits being which I wrote from right to left. The integrand being D² dx1 dy1 dx2 dy2

Comment: HallaSurvivor I wrote what I did, but I didn't get what is asked in the question so it would be of help if someone solves it.

Comment: see this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299709/expectation-that-the-distance-between-two-points-in-the-unit-disc-is-1

Comment: @SoumajitDas did I correctly typeset what you tried?

Comment: HallaSurvivor no the 1st integral on the left will be 0 to 1 and then so on. Like the fourth integral will be the first limit on the left

Comment: Justaguy thank you for the link but I'm not very convinced with that solution actually. 

Comment: @SoumajitDas what about now? You can also edit your question to put them in the right order if I got it wrong again

Comment: HallaSurvivor it's alright now. Thank you so much. A solution will be more appreciated

Comment: Duplicate of [Expectation that the Distance Between two Points in the Unit Disc is 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299709/expectation-that-the-distance-between-two-points-in-the-unit-disc-is-1). Which part of the solution here are you not convinced with?

Comment: Can't understand the part in the hint where the expectation of 2E(x0)E(x1) is becoming 0

Comment: $X_0,X_1$ are independent identically distributed. Try computing the marginal and then the $EX$